# Convert lists inside dictionary to strings?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {1092267: [0.187], 524292: [-0.350], 524293: [0.029], 524294: [0.216]}
```

So there is an ID followed by a value inside a list. I want the lists to be strings like this:

```
dict = {1092267: '0.187', 524292: '-0.350', 524293: '0.029', 524294: '0.216'}
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: all the answers given are giving me the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' when I use a bigger list

Comment: Regarding your EDIT: What exactly do you mean by "when I use a bigger list"? The error sounds like you're trying to apply the answer(s) to a string rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

[`iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) and [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to the rescue:

```
d = {k: str(v[0]) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
```

But please don't use `dict` as a name for your variable

Answer (score 2):

Use `iteritems` and `dict comprehension`.Dont use `dict` as variable name

```
>>>{i:str(j[0]) for i,j in dict.iteritems() }
{524292: '-0.35', 524293: '0.029', 524294: '0.216', 1092267: '0.187'}
```

In **Python3**

```
>>>{i:str(j[0]) for i,j in dict.items() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to this.

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    mydict.update({key: str(value[0])})
```

Output:

```
{1092267: '0.187', 524292: '-0.35', 524293: '0.029', 524294: '0.216'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in dict.viewitems():
    dict[key] = str(value[0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
{1092267: '0.187', 524292: '-0.35', 524293: '0.029', 524294: '0.216'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but Roman Pekar's answer is the right answer. But it won't work in Python 3.x as d.items now does wat d.iteritems used to do:

```
d = {k: str(v[0]) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
```

The solution in Python 3 therefore is:

```
d = {k: str(v[0]) for k,v in d.items()}
```

You may want to check if the value you are are trying to change is actually a list, in order to prevent errors:

```
d = {k: str(v[0]) for k,v in d.items() if isinstance(v, (list,))}
```

Output:

```
{1092267: '0.187', 524292: '-0.35', 524293: '0.029', 524294: '0.216'}
```